# Can I use the binding library of Aurelia, independently, in vanilla JavaScript +ASP.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, aurelia

I write vanilla JavaScript objects in my Views  in ASP.Net Core  (MVC + API), to handle all client-side functionality.

My goal is to build my applications as a PWA (progressive web app).
 So I could later add the full Aurelia framework.

For my objects, I would like to use, for the moment, 
only the binding library of Aurelia, independently. I know it is quite powerful.

Is it possible and how can I do it?

thanks.

Comment: I suspect it's possible, given Rob Eisenberg's history with Durandal and past viewpoints about 'use what you want'. I saw nothing that forces you to use the router or other aspects. I suspect you would just have to explicitly compose the top level view. But I have not tried it.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your application as a progressive web app and only use the binding library, but in reality it's just easier to use a few of the key libraries together for a better developer experience.  Just because you *can* do something doesn't always mean you should.

Take a look [here](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/app-configuration-and-startup/8) in the docs for a more thorough example, but in a nutshell it looks like this -

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-component message="Enhance Me"></my-component>

    <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
      SystemJS.import('aurelia-bootstrapper').then(bootstrapper => {
        bootstrapper.bootstrap(function(aurelia){
          aurelia.use
            .defaultBindingLanguage()
            .defaultResources()
            .developmentLogging()
            .globalResources('resources/my-component');

          aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.enhance());
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, for the moment, I am inclined to use a binding library with minimum dependencies. I am thinking 2 libraries, the aurelia's one or the rivetsjs